# Having problems trying to read a file using CLion with WSL toolchain

Tags: c, clion, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Code path is: `C:\Users\*****\CLionProjects\bst`

File path is: `C:\Users\*****\CLionProjects\bst\Resources\students`

File content is:

```
AB123456 ASD SMITH 1.0
AB234567 OMAR SDF 30.0
AB345678 XCV WER 69.0
```

My code is:

```
FILE *input = fopen("Resources\\students", "r");
if(!input){
    printf("Error while opening the file.");
    exit(-1);
}
```

and the output is:

```
Error while opening the file.
Process finished with exit code 255
```

I've also tried the absolute path or to change the file extension but the output won't change. I've never had this problem working on Linux. What should I do?

Comment: Hi. Sorry for stupid question. Your file path requires `.` in PATH. Do you have it? BTW what it your working directory when you run executable?

Does `/mnt/c/Users/*****/CLionProjects/bst/Resources/students` works as path to file?